# python class methods: parameter as class variables pros and cons

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, parameters

I'm quite new to Python oop. So, this class:

```
class Foo:
    def barfunc(self, baz):
        print baz
```

looks to me quite similar to

```
class Foo:
    def barfunc(self, baz):
        self.baz = baz            
        print self.baz
```

Output will, I think be the same, so I would like to know which is preferred and why. Maybe I miss major possible pitfalls from using one or another.

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors... (class declaration doesn't end with `()`, unless you're inheriting from something.. i.e. `class Foo(object):`. function declaration should end with `:`...). Further, class name should begin with capital case.

Comment: Have you been through the [Classes section of The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#classes)?

Comment: @ alfasin: ty, yes, I tiped it too quickly. Hopefully the question still shows through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your aim is to just print the `baz` once, then both are equivalent.

However, if you want to re-use `baz` later on in your code, then using the second one is the better approach, because you can add additional methods to access it now.

```
class Foo(object):
    def barfunc(self, baz):
        self.baz = baz            
        print self.baz

    def barbar(self):
        print self.baz
```

And now you can do

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.barfunc(10)
10
>>> f.barbar()
10
```

Comment: Oops, excuse me, but, for the record, there's a slight mistake in your example code, it should be: >>>f=Foo()
>>> f.barfunc(10)
>>> f.barbar()

Answer (score 2):

One major pitfall is your terminology - neither example shows a class *variable*.

In the first example, `baz` is an argument to an instance method and `baz` is only *available* in the local scope of that method.

In the second example, `baz` is an argument to an instance method and is assigned to an instance attribute, `self.baz`, within that method.  After the method has been called, `self.baz` will be available to all objects in the class instance.

Comment: ty, yes, i know i really suck at this. I'm quite overwhelmed with the terminology, but one great improvement over just yesterday is that I actually understood your post... :)

Comment: I would say that there are two separate ideas to learn : 1) what OOP is as a programming style, what its advantages are, how to structure a program using that style; and 2) how you implement that programming style in Python, the tools Python offers and how to use those tools.  Pyvideo.org is an excellent resource - [Python's Class Development Toolkit](http://pyvideo.org/video/1779/pythons-class-development-toolkit) comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

the first example will have effect only inside the function..but the second one will have effect in the entire class..

```
class foo():
    bar=1
    def baz(self,bar):
        print bar
    def baz1(self,bar):
        self.bar=bar
a=foo()
a.bar
#prints 1
a.baz(2)
#prints 2
a.bar
#here it prints 1 again because it is the class variable which is not affected by the baz() function's local variable
a.baz1(3)
#prints 3
a.bar
#here the class variable value changes to 3 because self.bar changes the value of bar in entire class
```

self is the entire instance of the class and it changes every value of the class when used that is it has a global scope or scope in the entire class.

run this example and ask if you have any doubt